# Is there any use of the XTHL instruction in an 8085 microprocessor?

Tags: x86-16, 8085

I understand what XTHL does, but can someone give an example of a scenario where one would actually use it? Moreover, if possible please share the code for the application as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One use includes passing arguments to assembly functions like this:

```
    CALL function_name
    DB   1,2,3 ;arguments
...
function_name:
    XTHL
    MOV A,M ;get argument
    INX H ;move to next argument
    ...
    XTHL ;now return modified return address to stack,
         ;also restoring HL contents as well
```

Other use is to have shadow copy of HL on top of stack, for example:

```
    DAD   B ;hl=hl+bc
    XTHL  ;'shadow' hl swapped in
    JNC   no_inc
    INX   H
no_inc:
    DAD   D ;hl=hl+de
    XTHL
    ;so we just added 32-bit number in DE:BC to HL:(TOS)
```

In similar way you juggle words that are pushed on the stack.

Some abuse also includes this:

```
    LXI SP,addr1
    XTHL
    LXI SP,addr2
    XTHL
    ...
```

this code will move chain of data words through locations pointed by consecutive `LXI SP,addr` commands. Of course, this requires interrupts disabling, but gain is speed.